# How to find out what's causing (broken) ajax login

Tags: login

I have inherited a pretty jumbled wordpress site. Just recently, my development version of the site has decided it uses some sort of ajax login, which brings up a throbber, then does nothing, after clicking login.

How would I go about finding the source of this problem?

Comment: Ajax login isn't part of wordpress by default, I guess it's a plugin, so deactivate it. Maybe it' part of your theme, then try using the default one for a first test.

Comment: Watch the browser console and the HTTP requests to see what is failing. That should narrow things down. When you have something specific perhaps someone here can help.

Answer (score 0):

I used firebug to investigate the throbber image and noticed that one of the classes mentioned contact-form-7, so I disabled that plugin. If the name of the plugin wasn't obvious I guess I could have searched for a file containing the alt text "Sending ..." and seen which plugin folder it was from.